# Custom providers using XML as their data store - should I use XPath/XSLT or DOM?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, xslt, xpath

I’d like to  learn how to create custom providers ( say custom membership provider or custom profiles ) that use XML as their data store. Is ( using C# ) best way to accomplish this using XPath/XSLT or DOM?

thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start at the [documentation for MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx), you will find plenty of links that walk you through how to implement custom providers.

These days, to deal with XML, my default approach would be to use the **LINQ to XML** classes ([XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) and friends).

Comment: Does learning LINQ to XML mean one doesn't need to know/learn XPath/XSLT and DOM?

Comment: You should be able to go a long way without knowing too much about XPath, although that will never hurt. The XML DOM is more or less obsolete, so yes: you should be able to get by without it at all.

Comment: Are XML DOM and XPath alternative technologies used to do the same job? If so, are you then implying if I ever decide to learn one of the two, I should choose XPath since XML DOM is on its way out?

Comment: XPath is a cross-platform DSL for specifying nodes in an XML infoset. It serves a different purpose than the DOM because you can't really *build* XML with XPath. LINQ to XML is what is supplanting the XML DOM on the .NET platform.

Comment: Uhm,t his is confusing.I did a bit of googling and it seems Linq to Xml can also(at least in some cases) suplement XPath and Xslt.Anyways,t hank you for your time and help